# Support request in identification - exotic plant

Tags: identification

Can I have your support in identifying this exotic plant please? Thanks,

[image]

Comment: By the way, I have received another suggestion that looks pretty close to the above shown plant, Raveana palm tree, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

I oscilate between [Chamaedorea elegans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaedorea_elegans) and [Dypsis lutescens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dypsis_lutescens). I think I am more inclined to say Chamaedorea elegans because it has more leaves for it's current height than my Dypsis and also the leaves from your picture look a little more flexible compared with Dypsis.

Comment: Thanks but the leaves are pretty narrow compared with the above mentioned Chamaedorea elegans; not so sure about the Areca too (Dypsis lutescens) as I've said. Meanwhile I've received another suggestion - a [Pygmy Date Palm](http://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/images/pygmydatepalm.jpg)(?) but again, they look different. multam Alina oricum :)

Comment: I've seen Chamaedorea for sale at Dedeman and it had narrow leaves like the one in your picture. The leaves were also thinner and the venation less indented compared with Dypsis.  But as I said, I'm not completely sure. Cu placere :)